# Multiplication of a character by another in C

Tags: c

I am not able to understand why the following C program returns a value 34?

```
int main(void)
{
    char c;
    char  c1='a', c2='b';
    c= c1*c2;
    printf("%d", c);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: char is 1 byte, maximum value is 128

Comment: What were you expecting it to result in?

Comment: As hex values for clarity, `0x61 * 0x62 = 0x2522` which won't fit a`char`, and is truncated to `0x22` which is decimal `34`.

Comment: Aside: you are using "return" in the beginner's way. The program "outputs" 34. it does not "return" it.

Comment: @WeatherVane  how does 0x2522 gets truncated to 0x22?

Comment: `0x25` is ignored becuase `0x2522` is too large. What remain is the r.h. part, `0x22` and that was the point of showing the values in hex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ascii value of "a" is 97, of "b" is 98. Since the `char` (which can be `signed char` or `unsigned char` [depending on implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054939/684229)) can hold maximum value of 127 for `signed char` (or 255 for `unsigned char`), you get:

97*98 [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) 128 = 34

well, in C notation:

```
(97*98) % 128 == 34
```

PS: replacing 128 with 256 gives 34 as well.

Comment: Whether `char` signed or unsigned is implementation defined. So it can hold even 255.

Comment: The conversion to a signed char is implementation defined and I know of no implementation which would make it modulo, the wrap around is more complex and will allow negative result.

Comment: @AProgrammer you are right, in this case it would be little more complicated than just regular modulo. Thanks for comment!

Answer (score 4):

Basically `char` is just a small integer.

Using [ASCII encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (the most commonly used encoding by far) the values for `'a'` and `'b'` are `97` and `98` (respectively).

When you do multiplication the `char` values are [promoted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to `int` values, so it's a simple `97 * 98` multiplication. The result of that is `9506`.

Now `9506` is to large to fit in a `char` variable so it's truncated. The result value is easier to see if we use hexadecimal notation: Decimal `9506` is hexadecimal `0x2522`. The value is truncated (through modulo with `128`) to `0x22` which is `34` decimal.

Answer (score 1):

It likely uses ASCII for encoding. In ASCII, `'a'` equals to `97` and `'b'` equals to `98`. Multiply them and you get `9506`. You are assigning it to a `char`, which is 8 bits on most systems. `9506` is 37 * 256 + 34, hence why you get `34` after it's truncated. This truncation happens because `char` is likely unsigned, an if an unsigned integer type can't represent the value, it's reduced modulo the maximum it can hold +1 (which is `256`, because an unsigned char can hold values up to `255`). This is explained [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic):

> Unsigned integer arithmetic is always performed modulo 2<sup>n</sup>  where n is
>   the number of bits in that particular integer. E.g. for `unsigned int`,
>   adding one to `UINT_MAX` gives ​0​, and subtracting one from ​0​ gives
>   `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: `char` can be either signed or unsigned. It is implementation defined.

Answer (score 0):

As Character range is between -128 to 127 or 0 to 255. In this case integer value for c1 & c2 are 97 & 98 respectively.
so c=c1*c2; will result into 97*98 = 9506, While saving value which exceed range it cycle back to the lower limit and continue.
just to cross check 9506 % 256 will give you result 34.